# In notepad++, how do I use find & replace to reorder elements with decimal numbers?

Tags: notepad++

Not sure how to phrase this, but I have a file with instances following this pattern:

```
:1.152283[%note = 'string:YES']
```

What I need is this:

```
[%note = 'string:YES']:1.152283
```

The number after the bracket can be anything, but always a decimal.  I have tried with regex \d+\ but it doesn't find anything.

There are 4000-odd instances of this that need changing.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    (:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\[\S+\s*=\s*\S+?\])
Replace: $2$1
```

### Demo

This regex pattern says to match:

- `(` capture in `$1`

  - `:` colon
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` an integer or float
- `)`
- `(` capture in `$2`

  - `\[` open bracket
  - `\S+\s*=\s*\S+?` contents inside `[...]`
  - `\]` close bracket
- `)`

Then we replace with `$2$1` to switch the two capture groups.